# Date validation failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, if-statement

I wish to check whether a one given date is less than the other date using JavaScript + jQuery.

However, when checking a date that is one day less than the given date, the condition is not met.

This is my code;

```
$('#payment_date').change(function(){
    payment_date_1      = String($("#payment_date").val());
    s_date_1        = String($("#s_date").text());

    payment_date        = new Date(payment_date_1);
    s_date          = new Date(s_date_1);

    if(payment_date<s_date){
        alert("please enter a correct date");
        $("#payment_date").val("");
    }
});
```

ex: when `s_date == '2013-07-02'` and `payment_date == '2013-07-01'` the condition is returning `false` rather than `true`.

My HTML:

```html
<span style="display:none;" id="s_date">2013-07-02</span>
<input type="text" value="" name="payment_data_info[payment_date]" id="payment_date" class="hasDatepicker" readonly="readonly">
```

Note; I have checked if both dates are valid, two dates are returning valid dates and the condition is working perfectly well for other instances

I just found out why; I'm using jQuery's date picker. Dates less than and equal to 2013-07-10 returns a valid date and dates less than 2013-07-10 and larger than 2013-06-30 returns an invalid date. Any idea why?

Comment: It may help to post your html.

Comment: nice lib for date manipulation and translation http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if variable declaration is the problem, than check if the string parsing returns the dates you're expecting. Maybe s_date and payment_date are invalid after all?

I expierenced difficulties too with the direct comparison (don't know why), so I used the valueOf-function to get values for comparison.

Comment: +1 you found her problem obviously the dates get not parsed correctly... using the comparator on date should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure it works ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/4MQkK/

```
payment_date_1  = "2013-07-01";
s_date_1        = "2013-07-02";

payment_date    = new Date(payment_date_1);
s_date          = new Date(s_date_1);

if(payment_date < s_date){
    alert(payment_date + "is lower than " + s_date);
}
```

Check your values of payment_date_1 and s_date_1 at least one of them could not be parsed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I hope it will help.

```
 $('#payment_date').change(function(){
        var payment_date_1 = $("#payment_date").val(); //add var
        var s_date_1 =  $("#s_date").text();  //add var

        var payment_date        = new Date(payment_date_1);
        var s_date          = new Date(s_date_1);

        if((payment_date.valueOf())<(s_date.valueOf())){
            alert("please enter a correct date");
            $("#payment_date").val("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: finally someone who understands my question. Thanks but its still returning false. :(

Comment: Hey now $("#payment_date").val() is returning invalid date. any idea why? how can i convert it to a correct date?

Comment: what it is returning ? Can you see to me the demo actually how it is working?

Comment: @guitarlass I think you are using datepicker.

Comment: you have a better option to check when you choose date from datepicker(i mean at the time when you click on date)

Answer (score 0):

2 Possible Causes:

1) Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, 
**if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g.  new Date(2013,13,1) is equivalent to new Date(2014,1,1),** 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

your date format is 'dd/MM/yyyy' but new Date () use format yyyy/dd/mm so 2013-06-30: 30 is month i.e. 30 month more then 06/01/2013 --> 06/06/2015 
you need to change the format. for example:

```
var myDate = "2013/01/30"

var split= myDate .split("/");

new Date (split[2],split[1],split[0]);
```

2) months in Date() in javascript they numeric 0-11. so 01/**03**/2013 changed to 01/**04**/2013

```
int month = myMonth -1; // for example: mymonth = 'March' => month = 2
can use new Date(2013,month,30);
```

Answer (score -1):

PLease create date objects and then check

```
var first = new Date($("#s_date").text());
var second = new Date($("#s_date_1").text());

if(first.getTime() < second.getTime()) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: im checking for dates not for time. using var does not make a difference

Comment: @guitarlass Ok,No issues.Please check.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```
var payment_date_1      = $("#payment_date").val();
var s_date_1            = $("#s_date").text(); or $("#s_date").val();
// IF s_date_1 is a input field then you have to use .val()
```

For typecast `String`. You can do

```
var payment_date_1      = $("#payment_date").val().toString();
var s_date_1            = $("#s_date").val().toString();
```

Comment: the kind of casting does not matter